# Favorite questions and answers from the second quarter of 2014

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from April 1st 2014 through June 30 2014.

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

**What was the best answer (IYHO) provided to a question that was closed?**

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

Comment: Am I still allowed to answer if my opinion isn't humble?

Comment: I took this great idea of a question type as an inspriation for a [similar query over on Movies & TV Meta](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1355/49). Thank you very much.

Comment: @Richard I suppose.

Comment: @JackBNimble Any thoughts of doing a "favorite questions and answers of all time" version of this?

Comment: @Beofett I am totally up for it.

Answer (score 7):

Two of my personal favourites:

- I really liked the answers and discussion on SQB’s question  **[How did Dumbledore, or anyone, know Lily had sacrificed herself for Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/59582/3567)**

  It’s a well-posed question that invites discussion, which is nice because I think a lot of the recent Harry Potter questions have focused more on trivia than discussion. There are several good answers with different, canon-supported theories.
- Richard’s answer to **[Does Batman use Linux?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/55045/3567)**

  I remember this question getting a lot of flak when it was first asked, and was quickly closed as opinion-based. I was pleasantly surprised when Richard managed to find not one, but *two* canon references to Batman’s computer.

Comment: I liked the batman one. I think the issue was that it got quite a few "jokey" responses very quickly. ..

Comment: @Richard: Partly that, but there were also people (including me) who thought the question was unanswerable without being silly.

Comment: The penguin comment was genuinely laugh out loud funny

Answer (score 5):

**Questions:**

- [Which are the Two Towers in Lord of the Rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59930/which-are-the-two-towers-in-lord-of-the-rings) by @Ram G Athreya.

  Deceptively "D'uh" obvious upon first reading and quite interesting to research in depth. I love questions that make me learn new things.
- [What's with Nimbus 2000/2001 naming?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55016/whats-with-nimbus-2000-2001-naming/55018#55018)

  Another deceptively obvious question where the canon answer existed and was very unexpected.
- [Can Avada Kedavra be used to kill more than one being?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/52274/can-avada-kedavra-be-used-to-kill-more-than-one-being/53173)

  A great question.

  What makes it special is that it contains both **the worst answer I saw this quarter (wrong logic, wrong facts, non-canon)** - which managed to accrue 4 upvotes nonetheless :( - AND aside from that, the worst answer given this year to any question by @Slytherincess (making 2 IMHO incorrect assumptions).
- [What was in the letter to the Dursleys Dumbledore left with baby Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/60278/what-was-in-the-letter-to-the-dursleys-dumbledore-left-with-baby-harry)

  Something I was wondering about for a while as well.
- [How did Voldemort know about the magic of Lily's sacrifice?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56879/how-did-voldemort-know-about-the-magic-of-lilys-sacrifice)
- [Victorian flower language by Snape](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/57300/severus-snapes-first-words-to-harry-potter-an-apology/57303#57303) question

---

**Questions: Honorable Mentions:**

- [If a death eater had sacrificed themselves for Voldemort - would that offer a protection to him similar to the one given by Lily for Harry?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55753/if-a-death-eater-had-sacrificed-themselves-for-voldemort-would-that-offer-a-pr/55762#55762)

  Made me cry "uncle" for lack of any canon answer I could find.
- [Why doesn't the Order use unforgivable curses in case of life threatening situations?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55143/why-doesnt-the-order-use-unforgivable-curses-in-case-of-life-threatening-situat/55175#55175)

  Allowed me to go all bullet-point-happy. My OCD thanks the OP.
- [Why was Cardinal Richeleu one of the main antagonists in 1632?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54527/why-was-cardinal-richeleu-one-of-the-main-antagonists-in-1632/54536#54536)

  Because it covered both Armand-Jean du Plessis (aka Cardinal Richelieu) who was one of my most favorite statsmen in history, AND Eric Flint's 1632 which is one of my favorite SF works.

---

**Answers:**

<sub>I mostly remember these because they were for the questions I asked, so there's a certain bias there</sub>

- [How do wizards prevent Accio-fueled robberies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/54595/how-do-wizards-prevent-accio-fueled-robberies/54623#54623)

  The answer by @alexwlchan is wonderfully canon including sourcing a canon source I wasn't even aware of before!
- [Would Severus Snape be classified with ASPD?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58648/would-severus-snape-be-classified-with-aspd/60309#60309) by @Slytherincess - [AND a competing answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58648/would-severus-snape-be-classified-with-aspd/58663#58663) by @alexwlchan. Amazing analysis
- [Would it be possible to create a wand more powerful than the Elder Wand?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53476/overpowering-the-elder-wand/56274#56274) by @Slytherincess.
- [Why didn't Quirrell keep the flying key?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/55559/why-didnt-quirrell-keep-the-flying-key) by @alexwlchan

  Especially since it was posted right after I made a fool of myself by commenting that there's no canon answer :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some of mine

- I really liked DVK's 
  [How exactly is the Secret Fire similar to the Holy Spirit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58854/how-exactly-is-the-secret-fire-similar-to-the-holy-spirit), a short but precise question that unleashed Jimmy Shelter's excellently researched answer. There were also several other questions on the topic of cosmology and metaphysics in the Legendarium which I enjoyed, like [The Valar and their power to create](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35471/the-valar-and-their-power-to-create) and [Did the force-like magic exist within LOTR books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59039/did-the-force-like-magic-exist-within-lotr-books/59043#59043).
- I had another one but then I noticed that it predated the quarter by a few days.