# Favorite questions and answers of ALL TIME

Tags: discussion, blog

[Beofett](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/users/1359/beofett) suggested we do an all time favorite question and answers post.

So I'll accept any question or answer that was asked since the beginning of the site. It doesn't have to be the most up-voted one or most viewed. Maybe it is the original question / answer that got you involved on the site. A brief explanation of why it is your favorite would be helpful.

The answers will be compiled into a blog post similar to [quarterly posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4793/favorite-questions-and-answers-from-the-second-quarter-of-2014?noredirect=1#comment13475_4793). The end of the quarter is coming up, I might still do a quarterly one or maybe I'll just skip it in favor of this one. Only Time will tell (and Time is being pretty close lipped at the moment).

Comment: Is Time a Time Lord?

Answer (score 7):

The reason I suggested it was because I re-read [this answer by Jeff](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/4059/1359) to [Are all Stormtroopers as poor soldiers as the ones in the movies?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/4056/1359), and thought (again) that this is my single favorite answer on the entire website.

It's one of those answers that just shattered my preconceived notions about one of my favorite titles in a way that makes me enjoy the movies more than I had originally.

Answer (score 5):

**Favourite Question:**

- [What is the song of ice and fire?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/51208/what-is-the-song-of-ice-and-fire)

A Pretty underrated question from [Shev](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/19374/shevliaskovic). It's one of those funny ones where you see it and you're like "why didn't I think of that?". The entire story hinges around this one simple line, and none of us questioned what exactly *is* the "song of ice and fire"...

**Favourite Answer:**

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/14281/21267

[Thaddeus](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2765/thaddeus) always takes the time to give us well-researched and wonderfully formatted answers, he even gives us a nice tl;dr for all of his answers. This one stands out for me as I really enjoyed the subject matter and all of the links and extra reading linked in the answer.

Comment: I was hoping that question would get some more answers

Answer (score 5):

Well, I have three questions favorited:

[Why didn't the Fidelius Charm on Shell Cottage stop the trio from Apparating there?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28184/why-didnt-fidelius-charm-on-shell-cottage-stop-the-heroes-from-apparating-there) asked by [*moi*!](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3500/slytherincess)  < / Miss Piggy> Actually, in hindsight, I'm not sure why I favorited this question ... maybe I was just trying to bookmark it or something.

[Is Slytherin Evil?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7403/is-slytherin-evil/7414#7414) is a far better question than the Shell Cottage one, IMO. *Is Slytherin Evil?* was asked by [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tango)

[Why did the Fidelius Charm on the Potters' house break?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/22550/why-did-the-fidelius-charm-on-the-potters-house-break) asked by [Kevin](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/3267/kevin)

[Is Santa Claus a Time Lord?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7837/is-santa-claus-a-time-lord), also asked by [Tango](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/1693/tango)

**ETA:** Oh, how could I forget?!  I asked [How was the sound of the Nazgul composed?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13092/how-was-the-sound-of-the-nazg%C3%BBl-composed) [Gabe Willard](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/4831/gabe-willard)'s answer was absolutely the most surprising and unexpected one I could have imagined! The question is just okay, but the answer is unbelievable.

Comment: The "Is Slytherin Evil?" question is another of my personal favorites.

Answer (score 4):

At the risk of a (probably fair) accusation of self-promotion, I was very happy with the detective work I got to do for [my answer to "Word for female dunedain"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56367/word-for-female-dunedain/56390#56390).  I understand why it only got +8 rather than the obvious +several billion it undoubtedly deserves (smiley goes here) since it was a farly niche-interest question, but it's still amazing what one can dig up in obscure footnotes and side-references.

Comment: No-one minds if **you** self-promote mate!

Answer (score 4):

- [Was Yoda fully sane on Dagobah?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6343/was-yoda-fully-sane-on-dagobah)

  > looks like a crazy hungry green thing that unfortunately has the ability to speak
- [Why do we hear Leia's Theme during Kenobi's death?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2810/why-do-we-hear-leias-theme-during-kenobis-death)

  Because I love music questions.
- [When Did George Lucas Make Up the Stuff About the Sith and Midichlorians?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7510/when-did-george-lucas-make-up-the-stuff-about-the-sith-and-midichlorians)

  Because I'm a masochist, I suppose.
- [Which are the Two Towers in Lord of the Rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/59930/which-are-the-two-towers-in-lord-of-the-rings/59934#59934)

  Deceptively simple and "obvious".
- [Why exactly do the Death Eaters serve Lord Voldemort?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2608/why-exactly-do-the-death-eaters-serve-lord-voldemort/2612#2612)

  - Because BULLET POINTS
- [Wasn't Harry's father just like Draco?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13052/wasnt-harrys-father-just-like-draco/13053#13053)

  Because I hate James Potter.

Comment: BIAS warning: most of these are answered by me.

Comment: The Yoda one is another of my favorites.

Answer (score 2):

I like this one; [Who, or what, are the human characters in the original 1977 Hildebrandt Star Wars poster?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/63180/who-or-what-are-the-human-characters-in-the-original-1977-hildebrandt-star-war?rq=1).

It took me a while to puzzle out why the poster (drawn **after** the film had been made) looked like it had completely different actors on it.

Answer (score 2):

[What is the origin of the phrase "on the gripping hand?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/392/19561)
...because I learned something that I didn't even know I *could* learn.

Comment: The gripping hand?

Comment: Yes. I knew the expression, but had no idea where it came from.

Comment: I just found it surprising that you forgot to end your sentence with "the gripping hand" (the gripping hand).