# Favorite questions and answers from the third quarter of 2014

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2014 through September 30 2014.

**Note: If you have a favorite question or answer outside of this date range, please post it to [Favorite questions and answers of ALL TIME](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5011/favorite-questions-and-answers-of-all-time) for a blog post that will be coming up in the bottom half of October.**

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

**What was the best answer (IYHO) provided to a question that was closed?**

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2013/07/01)

Comment: Your last one didn't come out right. I can still see part of the query (or what looks like most of it).

Comment: @Zibbobz I am not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Your link for "Questions with best answer created within 3 month range" doesn't show the results.  It just shows the query.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I failed to scroll down on the third link. It's working just fine.

Comment: Notes from Chat:

Phantom42 said http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/65951/is-big-brother-an-actual-person-in-the-novel-1984 and http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/68005/whose-underwear-is-this

Answer (score 2):

I thought this was a good question that provoked a pretty good range of answers;

[Why did the Matrix simulate 1999 instead of a pre-computer year?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/64415/why-did-the-matrix-simulate-1999-instead-of-a-pre-computer-year)

And I thought this was an especially good answer to a (seemingly) straightforward question;

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/65627/20774